# asp.net table cell horizontal allign

Tags: c#, asp.net, alignment

I have an asp.net table with 1 row and 2 cells in each row.
I am trying to get the right cell to display near the right most edge of the cell with no success.

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="tblMyTable" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="Black" Font-Names="Arial" BackColor="White" Width="190" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:TableRow Font-Names="Arial Black">
            <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="HeaderPadding">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblID" Text="361299"></asp:Label>
            </asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPercentage" Text="79%"></asp:Label>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
</Asp:Table>

<style>
.HeaderPadding 
    {
        padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
</style>
```

I want to display like this:

[image]

How can I align the percentage label correctly?

instead it looks like this for some cells but looks ok in others.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="HeaderPadding">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblID" Text="361299"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPercentage" Text="79%"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have found the culprit. In lower rows, I have cells which contain text of various lengths. This is turn seems to dictate how long the top cell is.

Comment: @sd_dracula If you want a consistent width that doesn't grow/shrink based on the data's length in the cell, consider using CSS `width` settings in `px` or `em`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css class like below

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .rightAlign { text-align:right; }
    </style>
```

in your label

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPercentage" Text="79%" CssClass="rightAlign"></asp:Label>
```